# I've implemented a code that will check if the user input value is single digit or double or triple or more than that

Tags: bash, scripts

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTnFE.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I6zP.jpg)

I'm having problem with the output. Please let me know where am I wrong.

Comment: See [Why are bash tests so picky about whitespace?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/why-are-bash-tests-so-picky-about-whitespace). You may find [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) useful as well.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just missing some `[`'s. Try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r num
if [[ "$num" -lt 10 ]]; then
    echo "Single"
elif [[ "$num" -lt 100 ]]; then
    echo "Double"
else
    echo "More"
fi
```